# Failed to load resource: Request timed out on Safari in my wordpress site

Tags: ajax, safari, request, timeout

I have wordpress site. Recently we have getting issue in ajax request.
In website,  we have open popup for register when I click on register and call ajax it's getting "Failed to load resource: Request timed out. "  on safari browser only

I tried with async:true, timeout and also setTimeout for solve this issue but no one working.

```
var request = $.ajax({
                url: jobifySettings.homeurl, 
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false
            }).done(function(response) {
                form.find( $( '.woocommerce-error' ) ).remove();

                var $response = $( '#ajax-response' );
                var html = $.parseHTML(response);

                console.log( response );

                $response.append(html);
                error = $response.find( $( '.woocommerce-error' ) );

                if ( error.length > 0 ) {
                    form.prepend( error.clone() );
                    $response.html('');

                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would say to keep async set to true in your ajax settings (which you said you tried), as this will make Safari hold the connection open until you get a response back (and then close it).

However, if this is not working on it's own for you, you could try adding a cross-origin 'CORS' header (Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*") in your htaccess file. If you have issues with CORS, this [troubleshooting link](https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/) may help.

Quote from link: (in case it breaks in future)

> ```
> <ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
>    SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.domain\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
>    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
>    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
>    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
> </ifmodule>
> ```